# How to select only some characters from MySQL field?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible and if so how to get only lets say 250 characters from a field with type "text" in my MySQL query?
Or should I better create a new field with type varchar(250) which would contain the brief text for article?

Comment: the latter one is always preferred. Especially if filled by human editor, not some artificial intellect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUBSTRING Function in MySQL:
For e.g.
`SELECT SUBSTRING('CYBERNATE', 2, 3)` would return YBE