# kohana orm retrieve only specified amount of characters from text column

Tags: php, mysql, orm, kohana, chop

Currently I am writing a website using Kohana framework 3.3. Today, I wanted to create subpage where user would be able to browse news, however I encountered a small problem with Kohana ORM.

I would like to retrieve only a dozen / several dozen characters from a text field, because loading the entire field would be a significant waste of server resources.

Does anyone know how I can achieve the same effect as in those cases?

- ↓ [MySQL/SQL retrieve first 40 characters of a text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080860/mysql-sql-retrieve-first-40-characters-of-a-text-field)
- (preffered) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left
- [How to select only some characters from MySQL field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530938/how-to-select-only-some-characters-from-mysql-field)

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What's the specific issue you are encountering?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with the ORM class. You can build your own query with Kohana's own query builder and the object can be returned as an ORM-model, therefore you fill in your ORM model name (e.g. 'my_orm_model') in the as_object function.

Combining one of your suggested links with Kohana's own Query builder you would get something like this.

```
DB::Query(Database::SELECT,"SELECT LEFT(field, 40) AS excerpt FROM table(s) WHERE ...")->as_object('my_orm_class')->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I'll use it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code behind ORM, it seems it's not possible to load a partial model. You may have to use the [Database_Query_Builder](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder) class, combined with [`DB::expr`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/DB#expr) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

ORM was designed for working with a whole records (queries like `SELECT * FROM ...`). You can store fulltext values in separated (MyISAM) table, so your ORM models will skip that field.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It's a pity that there is no ORM skip() function, which could ignore (unselect) specified fields or retrieve only specified amount of data.